# How can i make sprite appear 5cm in every screen and resolution in unity2d

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can i make a sprite size appear 5cm in every screen size and in every resolution in unity 2D? I can use canvas image also depending upon your suggestions i tried everything not working..

Comment: 5cm/10cm any constant Hight and width in every screen size and resolution

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Are you sure you are using this language? And just because you use a certain IDE (visual studio) doesn't mean your question is about that IDE in specific

Answer (score 0):

Write a script to resize the camera so that the object with world size (Width, Height) always exactly matches the camera horizontally or vertically, and see if you can fix the sprite size,This is my own understanding, and I don't know if it works or not.

[image]

Comment: [Why not upload images of code? - This also applies to answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Thanks for the reminder I'll keep an eye out

Comment: this script is totally working you are awesome but this is working only in one monitor like if i change the resolution in one monitor the sprite size is always the same but i want the same physical size in every monitor. Can you help me out with that ?

Answer (score 0):

Which view mode are you using for your game? Is it landscape or Portrait?
You can use 2960 X 1440 Landscape if you are using landscape mode, and 2960 X 1440 Portrait if you are using portrait mode from the resolution aspect in game mode. These are the highest resolutions for both landscape mode and portrait mode. When you open your game on any other resolution phone the resolution of your sprite will be set accordingly. Always use the highest resolution in this regard.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using Screen.dpi?

[Screen.dpi](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen-dpi.html)

like mentioned in [this post](https://forum.unity.com/threads/finding-physical-screen-size.203017/)?

Comment: I actually want this for every monitor screen so how can i get the dpi for every monitor and set the sprite size according to it?

Comment: If you don't get the info from the hardware, there is no way you can do that. Having a list of all devices and their resolutions in your own database is not suitable.

And not all devices give you the required information, unfortunately. So you can only make it work on _some_ devices.